# How to override the SBT repo urL for intelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, repository, ivy

I have IntelliJ iDea 207 and have just installed the scala plugin for it. I tried creating my first scala project in my office computer. The problem is that while building the project, it is unable to get the required sbt version from the repository as our organization blocks the central repositories. Hence, it ends up in build errors. How do I override the repo url to point to the url that works in our organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this in your `build.sbt` file.
`resolvers ++= Seq("scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases")`.

here add the repository url for your organisation.

Comment: you could do something like this - `credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "<host>", "<USERNAME>", "<PASS>")`.
refer - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/SBT+Repositories
and https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html